# TypeError: Button() takes no arguments

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a problem with my code, I hope someone can help me.
Here is my problem:

```
"C:\Users\Max Breier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Users\Max Breier\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\JaR\master.py" 
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max Breier\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\JaR\master.py", line 35, in <module>
    resume_button = button.Button(304, 125, resume_img, 1)
TypeError: Button() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And here is my code to create the button instances:

```
resume_button = button.Button(304, 125, resume_img, 1)
options_button = button.Button(297, 250, options_img, 1)
quit_button = button.Button(336, 375, quit_img, 1)
video_button = button.Button(226, 75, video_img, 1)
audio_button = button.Button(225, 200, audio_img, 1)
keys_button = button.Button(246, 325, keys_img, 1)
back_button = button.Button(332, 450, back_img, 1)
```

Here is the button code:

```
class Button():
    def _init_(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        action = False
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

        return action
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you make this a [MRE] that reproduces the error when run on its own?

Comment: Where does your button.Button() come from ? Did you follow a tutorial or something ?

Comment: I followed a tutorial

Comment: If you try running *just the code you've shown*, you'll find that it gives a different error, because `button` is undefined. Please include enough code that we can run *exactly what you post* and see the same error. (And ideally nothing more, so try to remove anything not relevant to your problem—but *make sure you check* that the reduced version still replicates the bug.) If you do that, we can probably help you. Otherwise, we're just blindly guessing. We have no idea what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You've misspelled `__init__` as `_init_`. You need double underscores. (For future reference, this code still isn't a [MRE], since it doesn't import pygame or define all your variables. But in this case it's enough to read and spot the misspelling.)